# How do I replace multiple items in a string?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

Starting string:

```
I like [dogs], [cats], and [birds]
```

Final output needed:

```
I like <a href="#">dogs</a>, <a href="#">cats</a>, and <a href="#">birds</a>
```

So basically changing items with brackets to links.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use this expression:

```
var str = 'I like [dogs], [cats], and [birds]';
alert(str.replace(/\[(.+?)\]/g, '<a href="#">$1</a>'));
```

- `\[(.+?)\]` asks for a literal `[`, to lazily match and capture anything, then to match a literal `]`. Replace with the captured stuff enclosed in `<a>` tags.
- The `g` modifier means global replacement, i.e. find and replace every match and not just the first.

[jsFiddle preview](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/CrR6U)

Comment: @Trufa: I would say, far from that.

Comment: that was the reason for the "?", comment gone!

Comment: Great solution. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 6):

It's a simple string replace.

```
function tagIt(source)
{
  return source.replace('[', '<a href="#">').replace(']', '</a>');
}
```